# Add new data input prompts to solicit 'meters' or 'feet'

Tags: python

I am stuck on a python program for an assignment. It asks the user to choose a metric of either 'meters' or 'feet'. I use a some if statements and they work but I am not sure how to put the words 'meters' or 'feet' to the numbers after.

> if metric == 'meters':
> print("Here is your calculated Total Volume:")
> print("You entered the width:   ", width)
> print("You entered the height:  ", height)
> print("You entered the depth:   ", depth)
> round 2 decimals places
> print("Calculated Total Volume: ",round(total_volume,2))
> print()
> if user chooses feet
> if metric == 'feet':
> print("Here is your calculated Total Volume:")
> print("You entered the width:   ", width)
> print("You entered the height:  ", height)
> print("You entered the depth:   ", depth)
> round 2 decimals places
> print("Calculated Total Volume: ",round(total_volume,2))

I tried using + "meters" after, width but It wouldn't work. It should say "You entered the width: 2 METERS" etc in the height, depth section as well.

Comment: Please [format](/help/formatting) the code in your question correctly

Answer (score 1):

Here you go bud

Code

```
meter = 3.28084

feet_to_meters = lambda feet: feet / 3.28084
meters_to_feet = lambda meters: meters * 3.28084

unit = input('feet or meters? ')
amount = int(input('amount? '))

if unit == 'feet':
    print(f'{amount} feet is {feet_to_meters(amount):.2f} meters')
else:
    print(f'{amount} meters is {meters_to_feet(amount):.2f} feet')
```